# How to export sqlite to CSV in Python without being formatted as a list?

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, export-to-csv

Here is what I currently have:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)
conn.text_factory = str ## my current (failed) attempt to resolve this
cur = conn.cursor()
data = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")

f = open('output.csv', 'w')
print >> f, "Column1, Column2, Column3, Etc."
for row in data:
  print >> f, row
f.close()
```

It creates a CSV file with output that looks like this:

```
Column1, Column2, Column3, Etc.
(1, u'2011-05-05 23:42:29',298776684,1448052234,463564768,-1130996322, None, u'2011-05-06 04:44:41')
```

I don't want the rows to be in parentheses nor have quotes nor the 'u' before strings. How do I get it to write the rows to csv without all of this? Thanks,

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you're currently doing is printing out the python string representation of a tuple, i.e. the return value of `str(row)`. That includes the quotes and 'u's and parentheses and so on.

Instead, you want the data formatted properly for a CSV file. Well, try the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html). It knows how to format things for CSV files, unsurprisingly enough.

```
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Column 1', 'Column 2', ...])
    writer.writerows(data)
```

The `newline=''` is apparently needed for correct escaping of newlines inside quoted fields.

Comment: @Dougal What is 'column 1'. Are these the database column's or are these the csv columns. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamAzam That's just literally printed out to the CSV file as the first (header) row. This snippet doesn't say anything about the database, just assumes it's gathered in a variable `data` in the order you want it.

Comment: `writer.writerow(['Column 1', 'Column 2'])` gives me error:`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
`. It is not the case when I open the file with `w` instead of `wb`. I commented out `conn.text_factory = str` in my code - I'm not sure whether it is relevant to the error I get.

Comment: Yes, sorry @JohnSmith, maybe this changed in the past 11 years or maybe I was wrong then – according to current docs it should be opened in text mode, not binary mode.

Answer (score 22):

my version that works without issues with just a couple of lines.

```
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file, isolation_level=None,
                       detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
db_df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM error_log", conn)
db_df.to_csv('database.csv', index=False)
```

If you want a table separated file, change the .csv extension to .tsv and add this `sep='\t'`

Comment: This is the best answer.  For modern versions of Pandas, it's best to use `read_sql`, so you don't need to worry about [lower level details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171611/difference-between-pandas-read-sql-query-and-read-sql-table).  See [here](https://mungingdata.com/sqlite/export-tables-queries-to-csv-parquet/) for more info.

Comment: @Powers it's fine until you have so much data that you need to stream it to the csv.

Comment: If the table is too big, this may cause system to hang due to memory insufficient.

Answer (score 14):

Converting an sqlite database table to csv file can also be done directly using sqlite3 tools:

```
>sqlite3 c:/sqlite/chinook.db
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .output data.csv
sqlite> SELECT customerid,
   ...>        firstname,
   ...>        lastname,
   ...>        company
   ...>   FROM customers;
sqlite> .quit
```

The above sqlite3 commands will will create a csv file called `data.csv` in your current directory (of course this file can be named whatever you choose). More details are available here: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-export-csv/

Comment: This is the best answer for me; thank you, it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

*I used a silly but easier one if only one table exists!*

**First I converted the database to a Pandas DataFrame**

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(database file)
df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from TABLE", conn)
```

**Then convert df to a CSV file**

```
df.to_csv(r'...\test_file.csv')
```

So a CSV file is creating under name of test_file.CSV