# Can Python print only selected fields from SQLite table to a file

Tags: python, sqlite, io

Please forgive me if my terminology is not right.  I have this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (field1 TEXT, field2 TEXT, field3 TEXT);
```

I want to print only information from field1 and field3 for each row into a text file.  What I've tried is:

```
e = open("export.txt", "w+")

sqlF1 = """
SELECT field1 FROM table1
"""
c.execute(sqlF1)
for row in e:
    #print c.fetchall
    e.write('%s\n' % row)

e.close()
```

The operation finishes without error but the text file is still empty.  I did a

```
SELECT field1 FROM table1
```

in the sqlite shell and data is there.

The end result is that I want to eventually have multiple fields piped to one line per row in a file.  I also want to put some text at the beginning and end of the values of each field I choose to pull this way.

Any advice or direction is helpful.  This operation doesn't have to be done with Python; I mean if I can figure out how to do it in conjunction with SQLite commands that would be OK too.

Thanks!!

Edit:  I think a variation on this might be what I'm looking for, yes?:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522830/how-to-export-sqlite-to-csv-in-python-without-being-formatted-as-a-listf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522830/how-to-export-sqlite-to-csv-in-python-without-being-formatted-as-a-list/%22How%20to%20export%20sqlite%20to%20CSV%20in%20Python%20without%20being%20formatted%20as%20a%20list?%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you are not iterating on the correct object.

```
for row in c.execute(sqlF1):
    e.write('%s\n' % row)
```

See the examples in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: That works.  But when I add more columns/fields like this:  SELECT field1, field3, FROM table1  I get an error "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"  and nothing piped to the file.

Comment: f.write("%s %s\n" % row) when you write two columns and so on. The "row" variable is a Python tuple.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks!  One of the fields is an integer. Example field1 text, field2 integer, field3 text.  I wrote %s %d %s, %s\n but I got error %d format a number is required (there are numbers in the fields)

Comment: Try to simply print the row variable in the console, maybe it will help. Check the types of the elements in the tuple. E.g. print type(row[0]), type(row[1]).

Comment: Thank you for all the help.