# difference between pandas read sql query and read sql table

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

Is there a difference in relation to time execution between this two commands :

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM TABLE',conn)
df=pd.read_sql_table(TABLE, conn)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I had trouble getting `pd.read_sql()` and `pd.read_sql_query()` to work with a postgres schema, used [d6tstack.utils.pd_readsql_query_from_sqlengine()](https://d6tstack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/d6tstack.html#d6tstack.utils.pd_readsql_query_from_sqlengine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will notice this difference.

Here is a source code for both functions:

```
In [398]: pd.read_sql_query??
Signature: pd.read_sql_query(sql, con, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, params=None, parse_dates=None, chunksize=None)
Source:
def read_sql_query(sql, con, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, params=None,
                   parse_dates=None, chunksize=None):
    pandas_sql = pandasSQL_builder(con)
    return pandas_sql.read_query(
        sql, index_col=index_col, params=params, coerce_float=coerce_float,
        parse_dates=parse_dates, chunksize=chunksize)
```

and

```
In [399]: pd.read_sql_table??
Signature: pd.read_sql_table(table_name, con, schema=None, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, parse_dates=None, columns=None, chunksize=None
)
Source:
def read_sql_table(table_name, con, schema=None, index_col=None,
                   coerce_float=True, parse_dates=None, columns=None,
                   chunksize=None):
    con = _engine_builder(con)
    if not _is_sqlalchemy_connectable(con):
        raise NotImplementedError("read_sql_table only supported for "
                                  "SQLAlchemy connectable.")
    import sqlalchemy
    from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData
    meta = MetaData(con, schema=schema)
    try:
        meta.reflect(only=[table_name], views=True)
    except sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError:
        raise ValueError("Table %s not found" % table_name)

    pandas_sql = SQLDatabase(con, meta=meta)
    table = pandas_sql.read_table(
        table_name, index_col=index_col, coerce_float=coerce_float,
        parse_dates=parse_dates, columns=columns, chunksize=chunksize)

    if table is not None:
        return table
    else:
        raise ValueError("Table %s not found" % table_name, con)
```

NOTE: i have iintentionally cut off docstrings...

Comment: Okay, so which one is recommended?

Comment: @NoName, use the one which is the most comfortable for you ;)

Answer (score 8):

I tried this countless times and, despite what I read above, I do not agree with most of either the process or the conclusion.

### The process

If you're to compare two methods, adding thick layers of `SQLAlchemy` or `pandasSQL_builder` (that is `pandas.io.sql.pandasSQL_builder`, without so much as an `import`) and other such **non self-contained** fragments is not helpful to say the least. The only way to compare two methods without *noise* is to just use them as clean as possible and, at the very least, in similar circumstances.

### The *assumptions*

There is a saying about assumptions... Between assuming the difference is not noticeable and bringing up useless considerations about `pd.read_sql_query`, the point gets severely blurred. The only *obvious* consideration here is that if anyone is comparing `pd.read_sql_query` and `pd.read_sql_table`, it's the table, the whole table and nothing but the table. Invoking `where`, `join` and others is just a waste of time.

Furthermore, the question explicitly asks for the difference between `read_sql_table` and `read_sql_query` with a `SELECT * FROM table`.

### My code

I ran this over and over again on SQLite, MariaDB and PostgreSQL. I use `SQLAlchemy` exclusively to create the engines, because `pandas` requires this. The data comes from the [coffee-quality-database](https://github.com/jldbc/coffee-quality-database) and I preloaded the file `data/arabica_data_cleaned.csv` in all three engines, to a table called `arabica` in a DB called `coffee`

Here's a summarised version of my script:

```py
import time
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

sqlite_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///coffee.db', echo=False)
mariadb_engine = create_engine('mariadb+mariadbconnector://root:admin@127.0.0.1:3306/coffee')
postgres_engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:admin@127.0.0.1:5432/coffee')

for engine in [sqlite_engine, mariadb_engine, postgres_engine]:
    print(engine)
    print('\tpd.read_sql_query:')
    startTime = time.time()
    for i in range(100):
        pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM arabica;', engine)
    print(f"\t[-- TIME --] {time.time()-startTime:.2f} sec\n")
    print('\tpd.read_sql_table:')
    startTime = time.time()
    for i in range(100):
        pd.read_sql_table('arabica', engine)
    print(f"\t[-- TIME --] {time.time()-startTime:.2f} sec\n")
```

The versions are:

- Python: 3.9.0
- pandas: 1.2.4
- SQLAlchemy: 1.4.13
- time: built-in

### My results

Here's a sample output:

```
Engine(sqlite:///coffee.db)
        pd.read_sql_query:
        [-- TIME --] 2.58 sec

        pd.read_sql_table:
        [-- TIME --] 3.60 sec

Engine(mariadb+mariadbconnector://root:***@127.0.0.1:3306/coffee)
        pd.read_sql_query:
        [-- TIME --] 2.84 sec

        pd.read_sql_table:
        [-- TIME --] 4.15 sec

Engine(postgresql://postgres:***@127.0.0.1:5432/coffee)
        pd.read_sql_query:
        [-- TIME --] 2.18 sec

        pd.read_sql_table:
        [-- TIME --] 4.01 sec
```

### Conclusion

The above are a sample output, but I ran this over and over again and the only observation is that *in every single run*, `pd.read_sql_table` ***ALWAYS*** takes longer than `pd.read_sql_query`. This sounds very counter-intuitive, but that's why we actually isolate the issue and **test** prior to pouring knowledge here.

I haven't had the chance to run a proper statistical analysis on the results, but at first glance, I would risk stating that the differences are significant, as both "columns" (`query` and `table` timings) come back within close ranges (from run to run) and are both quite distanced. In some runs, `table` takes twice the time for some of the engines.

If/when I get the chance to run such an analysis, I will complement this answer with results and a `matplotlib` evidence.

### Context

My initial idea was to investigate the suitability of SQL vs. MongoDB when tables reach thousands of columns. `pdmongo.read_mongo` (from the [`pdmongo`](https://pypi.org/project/pdmongo/) package) devastates `pd.read_sql_table` — which performs very poorly against large tables — but falls short of `pd.read_sql_query`.

With around 900 columns, `pd.read_sql_query` outperforms `pd.read_sql_table` by 5 to 10 times!

Comment: Just tested on a table with around 125k rows, pandas 2.1.0, SQLAlchemy 2.0.20.

- `read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table")` took around 100s
- `read_sql_table(table_name)` took around 200s

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is obvious, 
with 
`df=pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM TABLE',conn)`

you use sql query that can be complex and hence execution can get very time/recources consuming.

With

`df=pd.read_sql_table(TABLE, conn)`

you download a table and specify only columns, schema etc.

Answer (score 1):

In read_sql_query you can add where clause, you can add joins etc. and that way reduce the amount of data you move from the database into your data frame. It is better if you have a huge table and you need only small number of rows.

On the other hand, if your table is small, use read_sql_table and just manipulate the data frame in python. It's more flexible than SQL.