# Unable to download sqlite3 database

Tags: python

[image]

I am writing a code on replit and it works perfectly one the file I'm using. However since I want to try to  do sometihng to the database that I'm not sure will work I wanted to copy the database onto another replit file, so I tried to download it and then re - upload it onto another database file, and then use this code:

```
import sqlite3
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()
tabs = ttk.Notebook(root)
tabs.place(x=0, y=0)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabs)
tabs.add(tab1, text = "Workouts display")
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabs)
tabs.add(tab2, text = "Checkboxes")
root.title("Gym")
root['background']='red'
add = 0
connection = sqlite3.connect("My database.txt")
c = connection.cursor()

dictionary = [["Leg Day",0],["Shoulder Day",1],["Arm Day",2],["Back Day",3]]
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(tab1)
myList = tk.Listbox(tab2, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

c.execute('''
SELECT * FROM Workout
''')
root.mainloop()
```

to try and call this new database that I've uploaded on this "backup" file so that I can refer to if anything goes wrong in my original. However it's saying that the database disk image is malformed. I've tried several times and it's returning the same message:
"sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed"

Comment: Its a bit odd that your database is a ".txt" file (`my database.txt`). It may not really be a sqlite database.

Comment: Yea it for some reason downloads as a txt file. I tried to dowload it as an "All files" option too as one of my tries but that doesn't work either. My computer doesn't give me any other options of dowloading. Basically I don't know how to download or export sqlite3 database files while retaining their actual original form.

Comment: Btw it wasn't originally. It for some reason made me download it as a txt file

Comment: I added a picture as a hyper link on how my computer offers to download

Comment: Do look inside the file to see what it is. It could be mangled by CRLF encoding or who knows what. How can we reproduce this problem?

Comment: Another option? [How to export sqlite to CSV in Python without being formatted as a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10522830)

Comment: Have you perhaps considered opening that text file with a text viewer/editor?

Comment: You can also try to open you sqlite file with a sqlite viewer - if that works at least you know the db is okay (which I guess probably it isn't and probably you won't be able to open it with a sqlite viewer either)

Answer (score 1):

(Workaround at the end)

You see a combination of 2 things, I can replicate it too:

1. Your database file has no extension, and for some reason the browser slaps a `.txt` extension to it. This is not a problem, while it's not a real text file, it could work
2. If you click on the file on replit, you get to see it in a new tab, lots of red `NULL`-s. For whatever reason viewing the file affects how you download it (even if you close the tab with this strange content).

Created this fascinating test code, based on the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html):

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("tutorial")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE movie(title, year, score)")
cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO movie VALUES
        ('Monty Python and the Holy Grail', 1975, 8.2),
        ('And Now for Something Completely Different', 1971, 7.5)
""")
con.commit()

res = cur.execute("SELECT score FROM movie")
print(res.fetchall())
```

Running in place it produces the desired `[(8.2,), (7.5,)]` output, and creates the database file `tutorial`.
Now **DON'T click on the filename**, but click on the vertical `...` next to it, and select download. As a result you will get a **8192**-byte long `tutorial.txt`. Which you can connect to, and running the same code locally, with modified filename and removed `CREATE`/`INSERT`/`commit()` lines:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("tutorial.txt")
cur = con.cursor()

res = cur.execute("SELECT score FROM movie")
print(res.fetchall())
```

still produces `[(8.2,), (7.5,)]`.

Now click on the filename, `tutorial`, and see the lots of red NULL-s:
[image]
When you see this, the database can't be downloaded properly. If you click on download now, you will get a **8206**-byte long non-working `tutorial.txt`, which then dies on the `connect()` call. The file got longer, but not too much longer, which probably means that line-breaks are converted to 2-byte carriage-return + line-break sequences, what @tadman guesses in a comment.

However this is a UI bug, replit keeps the destroyed file on the client side, and will provide it for you to download. But the original file on the server still works, you just have to get rid of the one in your browser:

1. Make sure that the database file with its strange view is not open (inside the replit window/tab)
2. Do a clean reload of the replit window/tab (Ctrl+F5 or something like that)
3. Download the database file directly via the `...` menu, carefully avoiding to actually view the file.

Comment: Wow this just saved me hours of stupid other workarounds! Thanks @tevemadar!